# java GUI JLabel

Tags: java, user-interface, jlabel

I need a little help on java temperature conversion GUI

so here is my code for result

```
public class ResultsPanel extends JPanel
{
private JLabel result;
private JPanel panel;
final int WIDTH_CONST=120;
final int HEIGHT_CONST=60;

public ResultsPanel()
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH_CONST, HEIGHT_CONST));

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Result"));

    result = new JLabel();


    add(result);

}

public void setResultLabel(String str)
{   
    result.setText(str);
}

public void setResultLabel()
{
    result.setText("");                
}
}
```

so what I'm trying to do is, that when i click on the convert button i want to label the result

and here is my button handler class:

```
private class ConvertButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
       //calculate and convert temperatures
       //convert the temperature into String

        ResultsPanel result = new ResultsPanel();

        String temp; // temperature in string

        result.setResultLabel(temp);

    }
}
```

but it doesn't seem like it's printing out the result,

any help appreciated, thanks

update :

```
here is my tempGUI class:

public class TempGUI extends JFrame
{
private BannerPanel banner;
private TypePanel type;
private TemperaturePanel temperature;
private ResultsPanel results;
private JPanel buttonPanel;

private JButton convert;
private JButton clear;
private JButton exit;
public TempGUI()
{
    setTitle("Temperature Concverter GUI");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    banner = new BannerPanel();
    type = new TypePanel();
    temperature = new TemperaturePanel();
    results = new ResultsPanel();

    buildButtonPanel();

    add(banner, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(type, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(temperature, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(results, BorderLayout.EAST);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

public void buildButtonPanel()
{
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    convert = new JButton("Convert");
    clear = new JButton("Clear");
    exit = new JButton("Exit");

    convert.addActionListener(new ConvertButtonHandler());
    clear.addActionListener(new ClearButtonHandler());
    exit.addActionListener(new ExitButtonHandler());

    buttonPanel.add(convert);
    buttonPanel.add(clear);
    buttonPanel.add(exit);
}
private class ConvertButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        double celsius = 0, fahrenheit = 0;

        DecimalFormat decimalFormatter = new DecimalFormat("0,00");

        TypePanel type = new TypePanel();
        TemperaturePanel temp = new TemperaturePanel();
        ResultsPanel result = new ResultsPanel();

        String temp1 = "Test";
        result.setResultLabel(temp1);
        add(result);
    }
}

private class ClearButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        ResultsPanel results = new ResultsPanel();
        results.setResultLabel();
        TemperaturePanel temp = new TemperaturePanel();

    }        
}

private class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating the `ResultsPanel` but you're not adding it to any frame. Thus, the `ResultsPanel` is not displayed. You will have to create a frame for the `ResultsPanel` or add it to an existing frame like this `yourFrame.add(result)`.

Comment: actually that convertButtonHandler class is within a frame. and i added add(result) at the bottom of the actionPerformed and still didnt work

Comment: Can you add the code in question to your original question? `result` should not be visible outside of `actionPerformed()`.

Comment: You're already creating and adding a `ResultsPanel` object in the `TempGUI` initializer. As far as I can see there is no need to create a new `ResultsPanel` inside the `ActionListener`. Try making `results` a field of TempGUI and then call `setResultLabel()` on that field.

Comment: ohhh I see what i did wrong there. Haha, such a rookie mistake, thanks for you help marv!